# CORS issue with AdminLTE

Tags: adminlte

I try to use the AdminLTE template : https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE

To understand how it works, I try to use it localy. And I have this issue : no icons are displayed. See the picture :

[image]

And certainly because I have a cors problem (see the same picture).

To try this template, I did a simple html page :

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>AdminLTE 3 | Simple Tables</title>

<!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/admin-lte@3.1/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">

</head>
```

According the documentation it should be enough. And I do not understand where the problem could be.

### Edit

If I had manually the js ref to the glyphicons:

```
script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxxx.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script
```

Then it works normally. Even if I still have these CORS issues. I cannot continue like that of course, I must find why I have these issues.

Comment: Your server needs to be handling the font mime types correctly. Is this IIS?

Comment: no , only a single html page directly opened from the browser